# limit network bandwith for an ip

Tags: linux, networking, bandwidth, traffic-shaping

for a traffic management app i should limit bandwidth for clients ip addresses that for each ip there are different limit

how can use tc-tbf for specific ip address

or is any other solution?

Comment: The most simple way of doing it is: https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.ratelimit.single.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some days i do it

i use it for openvpn over freeradius

```
tc qdisc del dev br0 root
tc qdisc add dev br0 root handle 1: htb
tc class add dev br0 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate "LineBandwidth"kbit
tc class add dev br0 parent 1:1 classid 1:10 htb rate "MinUserBand"kbit ceil "MaxUserBand"kbit prio 2       #----- bandwidth and classid
tc filter add dev br0 parent 1:0 prio 2 protocol ip handle 10 fw flowid 1:10                                                        #----- MarkID1 and classId
iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -d "RealUserIP" -j MARK --set-mark 10                                             #----- RealIP and markID1
tc qdisc add dev br0 ingress
tc filter add dev br0 parent ffff: protocol ip handle 50 fw police rate "MinUserBand"kbit mtu 12k burst 10k drop    #----- BandWidth and MarkID2
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -s "RealUserIP" -j MARK --set-mark 50                                                  #----- RealIP and MarkID2
```

Answer (score 8):

In order to limit bandwidth of individual IP addresses, I have been TC with HTB. Here are some useful links:

- Homepage: http://luxik.cdi.cz/~devik/qos/htb/
- User Guide: http://luxik.cdi.cz/~devik/qos/htb/manual/userg.htm
- tcng is a relatively easy way to describe traffic control structures: http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-HOWTO/Traffic-Control-tcng-HTB-HOWTO.html

As a simple example, in order to limit bandwidth of individual IP addresses stored in CLIENT_IP shell variable, with limitations like the following:

- device name = eth0
- total bandwidth available/allowed for the device = 1000kbps up to 1500kbps
- default bandwidth (for clients that do not fall into our filters) = 1kbps up to 2kbps
- bandwidth of CLIENT_IP = 100kbps
- Maximum bandwidth of CLIENT_IP (if there is more bandwidth available) = 200kbps

Commands below would suffice:

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: htb default 10

tc class add dev eth0 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 1000kbps ceil 1500kbps 

tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:1 classid 1:10 htb rate 1kbps ceil 2kbps

tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:1 classid 1:11 htb rate 100kbps ceil 200kbps

tc filter add dev eth0 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match ip src ${CLIENT_IP} flowid 1:11
```

Answer (score 1):

Semi-related to your question, limiting a client's bandwidth is not likely the best solution, as it has to be on a client-by-client basis.  You may want to specify the maximum amount of bandwidth that any single client can consume, rather than specify by ip address.

Your best bet is going to be QoS, and specifying different priorities for services by type of traffic.

As far as I know, you can't use tc-tbf for a specific IP address.

http://man.he.net/man8/tc-tbf

If you're simply trying to improve performance, look at this article.

http://lists.debian.org/debian-firewall/2005/07/msg00088.html

Answer (score 0):

This article describes how you can use iptables to rate limit new connections: http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/187

You could drop the stateful check for NEW and instead restrict it by source IP.

Comment: That's for limiting connection attempts. The question is about limiting the bandwidth, so this article is irrelevant here.